# Angular 1.5 component access ui-router $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using the new `.component()` method introduced in Angular 1.5.x and AngularUI Router 1.0-alpha, how can I access the current router state from inside a component?

For example (i'm using ES2015 here and follow [Todd Motto's Angular Styleguide](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide)):

```
import angular from 'angular';

const header = angular
    .module('header', [])
    .component('header', {
        template: `
            <p>{{$state.current.name}}</p>
        `
    });
```

*Note: header is a child component, ui-router is injected and configured in a parent component.*

But `$state.current.name` or even simply `$state` doesn't display anything in the component's template.

The global idea of what I'm trying to do is setting a class on the header depending on the current state of the application.

I've tried to set the state on `$rootScope` but it doesn't work either... I'm probably missing something since I'm quite new to Angular, so maybe someone has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You inject it to the controller:

```
import angular from 'angular';

const header = angular
    .module('header', [])
    .component('header', {
        template: `
            <p>{{$ctrl.$state.current.name}}</p>
        `,
        controller: ['$state', function($state) {
            this.$state = $state;
        }]
    });
```

**Do note** the `$ctrl` in the template!

Comment: That's right, thanks! As my component never had a controller, I haven't thought to create one just to pass that $state :)